# Title Name Page PHP confusion

Tags: php

So lets say i have a php file that contains

`$title="Website | Categories";`

And my header.inc file includes     `<title><?=$title?></title>` which will output the title name.

But lets say i also have a variable on my php page called `'cat_name'`

How can i add 'cat_name' into `$title="Website | Categories";` Would it be like 
`$title="Website | Categories 'cat_name'";`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These will work:

- `$title = "Website | Categories " . $cat_name;`
- `$title = "Website | Categories $cat_name";`

This will not work:

- `$title = 'Website | Categories $cat_name';`

If a string is in double-quotes it will parse any variables inside of it. However, if the string is in single quotes it will not.

If you want to get a little fancier there are various ways to append the category name with another vertical pipe, like `Website | Categories | My Category`.

The simplest is probably using the ternary operator to detect if `$cat_name` is set and append text to the $title string.

```
$title = "Website | Categories";
$title .= (isset ($cat_name)) ? " | $cat_name" : "";
```

You could also create an array and add each element of your navigation to it (Website, Category, cat_name, sub_cat, sub_sub_cat, ...) then use an implode statement to turn it into a string.

Comment: Note: I don't believe the ternary example necessarily has to be split into two lines like that. However, I find it to be much more readable that way.

Answer (score 4):

`$title="Website | Categories " . $cat_name;`

Comment: Might want to tag a space onto the end of the first string.

Answer (score 3):

```
$title="Website | Categories $cat_name";
```

Comment: `$title="Website | Categories {$cat_name}";` this is the other correct way.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/de/language.types.string.php <-- PHP Doc says we're both right.